# CamScanner: Trojan detected by ESET

Tags: malware

I usually use [CamScanner](https://www.camscanner.com/) to scan my documents. After updating to the last version, [ESET](https://www.eset.com/int/home/mobile-security-android/) told me I have to remove it, because this app has [Trojan](https://www.virusradar.com/en/Android_TrojanDropper.Agent.DEB/description) and it can provide remote access to the infected device. That was strange for me, and I think it's not correct. Anyway, I'm not sure. Shall I really remove `CamScanner`?

Comment: Did you download it from the official website, or from [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.intsig.camscanner)? (Just a slight curious why they hosted their APK instead of linking it to Play Store...) Anyway, [VirusTotal for their latest APK from their site](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file-analysis/ODkwYzU5Mjk5NzU3YzBjYmIyNDg0NWNkMGEwZTQwNWM6MTU2NDI1MTE2NQ==/detection) only mentioned ESET, but looks like [the bundled ad](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/6440c585ddbe7e955fb428c1fba2e3b99d814c379ef8247dc7518ee5049cb250/relations) *might* contain trojan.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall the app. Google Play Store has removed it, and the company behind the app itself has [accepted](https://www.androidauthority.com/camscanner-malware-play-store-1023576/) that an ad module was acting as a trojan. The latter claims that their new version available from their website is free from that trojan though.

Comment: It seems that if you use version **5.12.5**, that would be fine and there is no need to uninstall the app. Otherwise, you can update it to the latest version from [here](https://www.camscanner.com/disclaimer/gpRecovery).